# Mac OS10.6.8 - A way of deleting or removing files from a folder, using a list of file names?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macos

I have a folder with 2508 files (jpg and pdf) in it on my drive. I have a list in a .txt file of about 1000 files which I want to remove from that folder - either by deleting to trash, or removing to another folder.

Is there a utility - or possibly commands I can put into the terminal - which I can use to do this, without manually moving files while looking through my list?

(Context: The list is a list of orphaned image files put out by Dreamweaver - which I want to remove from the images folder of a given site)..

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the terminal:

```
cat filename-of-list-with-files | xargs rm
```

Comment: Sorry - can you explain what this does? How does it relate to the list of filenames I have?

Comment: cat concatenates files and writes to stdout. xargs reads arguments from stdin and hands them to a specified command in as-large-as-possible batches. This asks xargs to apply rm to the files named in filename-of-list-with-files. Note that this does not work for files with spaces in their names.

Comment: Okay .. Thanks ... So I put that into my terminal, and it returns me my list of files with returns as backslash n's, and a comment "File name too long" - as though its treating it like one filename .. Is there a way for it to see the list as a list of multiple files rather than just one file?

Comment: It sounds like you have the actual characters `\n` instead of regular newlines. The default for xargs is to treat each separate line as one argument.

Comment: @Emil You can also have this problem when the file was created with a different encoding - from memory a windows standard is \r\n whilst *nix uses \n, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you ... But the .txt file has returns, or newlines, not \n as such -- the /n's only appear when its pasted into the command line. Should I save the file in a different format perhaps? I'm working entirely on Mac ... Thanks again .. We're getting somewhere, although not quite there yet. I'm obviously a total newbie when it comes to the Mac command line.

Comment: Actually - correction: Its a .rtf file ... I might try a different format tomorrow

Comment: You should try a regular text file, with no formatting at all. Try to just `cat file` before you add the xargs part. That way you'll see the contents of the file in raw text format.

Comment: I try a utf-8 text file called orphans4.txt or orphans4 (no extension but still a txt file as opposed to an rtf file) -- and cat orphans4.txt or cat orphans4  returns me this:  .pdfcy.pdf

Comment: All I have in the file is a straight list of filenames, mostly jpg files, separated by simple (invisible) returns